# connect a usb drive on windows without mounting it and without assigning a letter

Tags: windows, mount, usb-storage

To protect my backups from ransomware, I want to use my backup USB drive without never ever assigning a drive letter to it. I know how to do it with network disks, but how do I do it with USB drives?

Comment: Should be the same approach you use, not to assign a drive letter, to any partition.  have you tried that?

Comment: as soon as I connect my drive to the usb, windows recognizes it as a usb storage and assigns a letter to it. My question is how to avoid it.

Comment: You change your configuration where you have, manually whitelist the drive, before a drive letter is assigned to it.  That would only get you half way, you would still have to, manually unassigned the drive letter when you don't want a whitelisted drive to be mounted.

Comment: could you please transform your comment into a more detailed answer? I don't quite understand what you mean by "manually whitelisting the drive" and what is the command or the procedure to do it.

Comment: Windows allows you only connect certain USB devices, you can extend that to, only allowing certain mass storage devices, this allows you to mount the drives manually when you want them.  It's not an answer just an idea